# Free up not used View when creating new ones

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-arrayadapter

I got two kind of ArrayAdapter in my Application which load both (more or less) dynamically data.
The first one is bound to a thread which fires each second to refresh the data.
The second one refresh the data with a onClick action.

Now when i run my application i can see in with dumpsys meminfo that the View counter 
is constantly increasing (while on the fragment with the thread). 
Obviously this causes a huge memory leak after a few seconds/minutes. The same
does happen for the onClick one.

My assumption is that those "old" data are still stored inside those view and won't
get freed. Is there a way to remove each old view?
My adapter is located here; https://github.com/Blechd0se/android_packages_apps_AeroControl/blob/master/AeroControl/src/com/aero/control/adapter/AeroAdapter.java

The main method which use the adapter is here (createList()); https://github.com/Blechd0se/android_packages_apps_AeroControl/blob/master/AeroControl/src/com/aero/control/fragments/AeroFragment.java

Or is there another way to just free up those unneeded Views?

**EDIT:**
I found a solution if anybody is interested;
As described i need to use the notifyDataSetChanged()-Method whenever i change the data.
This is only possible if working with List. In my example its `List<adapterInit>` which alows
me to use the mentioned method as well as `clear()`. Also setAdapter on each second
is a very bad idea. Now i change only the data and the result is as expected. The View-Count
went down from ~15.000 to 100-200.
A patch can be found on my github.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears (from the code below) that you are refreshing the data by creating  a new adapter rather than telling the adapter that the data has changed.  Try passing the data to the adapter and then calling notifyDataSetChanged();

This will keep you from spamming a dozen new views every second.

Second, you may want to see if the garbage collector is cleaning these up at some point.  Since you were creating multiple views a second, you were probably creating views faster than the gc could reasonably keep up.  It might have paused your program if it reached a critical point (not sure).  See if you will actually crash due to out-of-memory to see if it is actually a memory leak.

```
   private RefreshThread mRefreshThread = new RefreshThread();

    private Handler mRefreshHandler = new Handler() {

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

            if (msg.what >= 1) {


                if (isVisible() && mVisible) {
                    createList();
                    mVisible = true;
                } else {
                    // Do nothing
                }

            }
        }
    };

public void createList() {

    // Default Overview Menu
    adapterInit overview_data[] = new adapterInit[]
            {
                    // First Value (0) is for loadable images.
                    new adapterInit(getString(R.string.kernel_version), AeroActivity.shell.getKernel()),
                    new adapterInit(getString(R.string.current_governor), AeroActivity.shell.getInfo(GOV_FILE)),
                    new adapterInit(getString(R.string.current_io_governor), AeroActivity.shell.getInfo(GOV_IO_FILE)),
                    new adapterInit(getString(R.string.current_cpu_speed), getFreqPerCore()),
                    new adapterInit(getString(R.string.current_gpu_speed), AeroActivity.shell.toMHz((AeroActivity.shell.getInfo(gpu_file).substring(0, AeroActivity.shell.getInfo(gpu_file).length() - 3)))),
                    new adapterInit(getString(R.string.available_memory), AeroActivity.shell.getMemory(FILENAME_PROC_MEMINFO))
            };

    listView1 = (ListView) root.findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    adapter = new AeroAdapter(getActivity(),
            R.layout.overviewlist_item, overview_data);

    listView1.setAdapter(adapter);

}
```

Comment: Even if i add something like; if(adapter != null) new adapter else adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() it still won't work. The views keep growing and i have no clue why. I tried to change the data structure to a List, so i can call the clear-Method, but still it will create endless views.

Comment: I see your latest edit, problem solved?  I have some guesses I can add if you're still having trouble.

Comment: Yes problem mostly solved. Thank you very much! The only downside; it creates now a new view (listview) on each onPause() -> onResume() which is kind of ok. If you have also a solution for that i would be very happy.